# Redirect Fisrt time login with LDAP

Tags: hooks, users, redirection

The first time that the user login to the page, have to be redirected to the user edit profile to fill a field (Id) that is mandatory at the first login, I tryed using drupal_goto at hook_user_insert and hook_user_presave and don't worked. How can I do that? In which hook I can do that?

EDIT: I am using LDAP Authentication, user don't have to fill a form registration.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules)? You should be able to react to a user login and set an action to redirect to the appropriate path

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, I could do it, no with Rules module. I did it using hook_user_login(), and $_GET['destination'].

```
    function webform_sub_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
    $currentuser = $edit['uid'];
    $_GET['destination']= "/user/".$currentuser."/edit";
    }
```

If it can cause problems, let me know. But for now it seems to work well.